# How does a compass work?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, geomagnetism

When using magnets, 
How does a compass determine the quantitative  value of the magnitude and the direction of the magnetic  field?

Comment: It doesn't determine the magnitude, only the projection of the direction in one plane.

Comment: Is there a device that can determine the magnitude?

Comment: Sure, [there are many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer), working on all kinds of different physical principles. Probably the most common are Hall sensors.

Comment: Is it still applicable when the earths poles aren't  used but another magnetic field??

Comment: Sure, a magnetic field is a magnetic field, no matter what the origin is. However, some magnetometers are better suited for certain applications/situations/field strengths.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675851/59023

Answer (score 2):

One wouldn't use this method outside an undergraduate laboratory, but it is possible to use a compass to determine the strength of the horizontal component of a magnetic field...  Displace the compass magnet by a small angle (say < 10°) from its equilibrium position, that is aligned with the  local magnetic field. The needle will return towards its equilibrium position in a series of damped oscillations. Provided the damping is quite light (and, unfortunately, most modern compasses are liquid-filled, so too heavily damped), the period of oscillation is
$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac I{mB}}$$
in which $I$ is the moment of inertia of the magnet/needle assembly and $m$ is the magnet's magnetic moment. [The constant $I/m$ is found by measuring the period of oscillation in a known magnetic field.]

Answer (score 0):

The earth has the North Pole and the South Pole, they have magnetic fields which flow from North to South. A compass needle tracks onto these magnetic fields, and therefore pointing Noth (the Geographical North Pole is actually South facing).